# webview(wkWebView) ios startProvisionalnavigation on the main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview

I need to run the **webview(WKWEbView)** on the main thread. I am getting to success with the **dispatch_get_main_queue**.

i.e.

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        [thisClass alertView]; // alertview method show a webview..
    });
```

//webview is showing on the app perfectly.

Now, I want to put progressbar(rendering process) before opening up a webview. as
Individual on main thread below methods are working fine.
But my **webView** in in another thread.

How can I call below method or attach to that with **webView(WKWEbView)**

```
-(void)webView:webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation{
    NSLog(@"Call ::didFinishNavigation");
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}


-(void)webView:webView didStartProvisionalNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation{
    NSLog(@"Call :: webViewDidStartLoad");
    indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    indicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
    [indicator startAnimating];
}
```

Que 1: Is it possible to all default method from another thread?

Que 2: Que 1 -> Yes, How ?

Comment: What do you mean by "But my webView in in another thread." As far as I can see you are using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() to load web view, so your web view is getting loaded on main thread and so is your activity indicator. What is the problem ?

Comment: first try this than my answer [self.view addSubview:indicator]; change this with [self.videowebView  addSubview: indicator];

Comment: @SandeepBhandari , webview is loading but indicator is not loading. I checked the logs neither didStartProvisionalNavigation nor didFinishNavigation method working for this.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. Even it will work *sometimes* you will get strange errors in the Crash Logs if you distribute your app over the App Store. You should always run all UIKit and WebKit operations in the main thread.